# What string value will sort after text when using ORDER BY on varchar field

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I'm dealing with a table that includes a list of names (type VARCHAR). Some of the names in the list will be replaced with some text due to confidentiality reasons. For one of our reports, we're running the following query (names have been replaced to protect the innocent).

```
SELECT * from PeopleData
  WHERE [location] = 'Somewhere'
  Order By [name] ASC
```

I'm not looking for a new select statement, but **a possible value** for a [name] cell that will cause the row to be sorted to the bottom of the list when this query is performed. If I use an empty string, it sorts to the top of the list. If I use a space, it sorts to the top of the list. I've even tried using a | character, since it's ASCII value is higher than any text, and it still sorts to the top of the list.

EDIT: The other criteria is that it can't be terribly obvious that the names were removed, since this list data is public. That means no 'ZZZZZZZZZZZ', and no '** CONFIDENTIAL **' values. Looking for something that's not screaming "TOP SECRET".

Any suggestions?

Comment: what row do you want to put at the end? I understand the list you mean here of course contains all the rows returned by the SELECT query, so what row should be always put at the end? it should depend on some condition.

Comment: The rows where the names are substituted with the string value I'm looking for.

Comment: Won't any value repeating at the end of the list be pretty obvious? You could generate random fake names if you wanted, or random initials.

Comment: @GoatCO: that's one possibility down the road, but I'm looking for a cheaper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use any value you like and add to your `ORDER BY` statement to force the ordering:

```
  SELECT * from PeopleData
  WHERE [location] = 'Somewhere'
  ORDER BY CASE WHEN [name] = 'Protected Value' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, Name
```

You could change the `CASE` statement to use some other criteria, like a `Masked` flag value rather than a specific set value if you wanted to randomize the masked names.

Comment: I was going to mention that the middleware we use to access this query parameterizes the order by fields. But when I passed your order by clause through the middleware, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem where I can control the text, but not the SQL Statement and I wanted to force a single entry to the end of this.

A bit kludgy, but I opted to prefix every in the list with hyphen ("-") EXCEPT the one I wanted at the end.

E.g.

```
- Apple
- Banana
- Carrot
A thing I wanted to be last
```